# How can I redirect to user requested url after login - Django loginrequiredmixin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to limit the access for a view using **Django LoginRequiredMixin**. If the user is not logged in it will redirect to the login page. But the problem is that after login it is not redirecting to the user typed url instead it goes to the default page?

For example user tries to login to the page **site/site-create**. If the user is not logged in it goes to the login page. After the login it goes to the default page of login.Here I want to redirect the user to **site/site-create** page.Example view

```
class CreateSite(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Site
    fields = ['name','site_category','description',]
```

Login/views.py

```
class LoginViewClass(FormView):
    """
    Provides the ability to login as a user with a username and password
    """
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'login/login_view_class.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(LoginViewClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       create_all_menus(ALL_MENUS)
       return context

    def post(self, request):
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

**Edit-->** login views.py added
 How can I do that? Thank You

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, but you need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: why? I thin the question is clear

Comment: What authentication backend are you using?

Comment: using django and its default autentication

Comment: In order to help you community need to know lot of details just like what @PacoH.is asking and if there's code you need to show that as well.

Comment: Can you add a simplified version of one of your views with `LoginRequiredMixin`. Only with the initial attributes, without methods that you might define.

Comment: @PacoH. example view is added

Comment: The problem is probably worth your login view / template, which you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @Alasdair login/views.py added

Comment: Django comes with [built in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views). The Django login view will handle the redirect, so the easiest solution is to use it rather than writing your own. If you must use your own login view, you'll have to duplicate the code to handle the redirect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `LoginRequiredMixin` will redirect to the `login_url` adding the originating URL as a parameter `redirect_field_name` [(link to code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/52eb5b289e9a0c2dc2302437b9590d0ce5ae0455/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L44).

`login_url` and `redirect_field_name` are two attributes you can define in your view like this:

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

This example would redirect to `/login/?redirect_to={current_url}`

This two fields have default values when there are not specified:

- `login_url` defaults to `settings.LOGIN_URL` [(link to code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/52eb5b289e9a0c2dc2302437b9590d0ce5ae0455/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L21)
- `redirect_field_name` defaults to the value `next` [(link to code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/52eb5b289e9a0c2dc2302437b9590d0ce5ae0455/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L15)

---

In your case it seems that your login view doesn't take the `next` URL parameter. The two options are:

- Change the login view take the `next` URL parameter.
- Change your view to send the correct redirect field name by adding `redirect_field_name = 'your_field_name'`